# Payment options are not disyplaying at checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

The payment options are not disyplaying at checkout page if I chose a another country then Germany:

[image: payment methods for other countries]

But if I chose Germany it looks fine:

[image: payment methods for germany]

I don't know were the problem is, because no error log will be generated and the settings for paypal as example looks like:

[image: payment settings for paypal]

but if I chose Italy for example the payments options not showing up :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

It's possible that you're setting the allowed countries in the wrong configuration scope.  Change your configuration scope while in your payment methods to ensure that the settings are correct for your Store View.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the problem was a condition in the methods.phtml-File for payment on pickup. I changed this and it works now :)